# Delete any MySQL records made within ten minutes of another record belonging to the same user

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mariadb

I have a table for a Rails app containing views by `users` on `projects`. Each record has `user_id` (bigint, foreign key), `project_id` (bigint, foreign key) and `created_at` (datetime).

The app currently records a view every single time a project's "show" action is called, meaning that users can (and do...) inflate the view count on each project by repeatedly reloading the page.

I'm planning to update the controller to record a view on a given project by a given user only once in a ten-minute period - a debounce for views.

My question is how do I construct a query in MySQL to remove previous "duplicate" records made within ten minutes of a previous one by the same user on the same project? Is it possible, or will I just have to do it in Ruby as a migration or a rake task?

Answer (score 0):

You are much better off solving this problem at source (i.e. not creating an entry for the current user in the case of reload).

You can use the YEAR(), MONTH(), DAY() and MINUTE() functions on the created_at to select or in your case delete record by minute on same year / month & day for given user.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I'm going to solve the problem at source; I was just trying to figure out how to remove all the duplicates that have already been created.

Comment: Totally untested so make sure to test but something similar to the following might work. DELETE p1 FROM projects p1
        INNER JOIN
    projects p2 
WHERE
    p1.id < p2.id AND p1.user_id = p2.user_id AND
    DATE_ADD(p1.created_date, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) < p2.created_date;